# F#: How do I declare and use ByRef semantics on parameters?

Tags: ado.net, f#, pass-by-reference

I am wraping some SQL Stored Procs with in/out parameters. This of course means I have to do ugly stuff like declare my parameters as by reference and use mutables.

How would I do this in F#?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

F# does indeed have a [`byref` parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233213(VS.100).aspx). Here's an example from the MSDN page:

```
type Incrementor(z) =
    member this.Increment(i : int byref) =
       i <- i + z
```

Mutable variables also exist (though there's an important difference between using `ref` and `mutable` variables, either of which can be used for many of the same purposes). The [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233186(VS.100).aspx) on this subject is very informative - including a discussion of when to use which keyword/construct.

Example of reference variables:

```
// Declare a reference.
let refVar = ref 6

// Change the value referred to by the reference.
refVar := 50
```

Example of mutable variables:

```
// Declare a reference.
let mutable refVar = 6

// Change the value referred to by the reference.
refVar <- 50
```

As you can see, the syntax for assignment (as well as retrieval) differs between the two constructs, too.