# F# byref param not mutable

Tags: f#, overriding, mutable, byref

I need to assign to a byref parameter, but, using F# 4.0 and .NET 4.5.2 on a Windows 8x64 box, I keep getting complaints that `This value is not mutable.`  I can't change the signature, because I'm implementing a COM interface.  Minimal broken example:

```
module Utils = 
    let bugFix1([<System.Runtime.InteropServices.Out>] ID : System.String byref) = ID <- "Hi!"
    let bugFix1([<System.Runtime.InteropServices.Out>] ID : int byref) = ID <- 0
    let bugFix1([<System.Runtime.InteropServices.Out>] ID : System.Guid byref) = ID <- System.Guid.NewGuid()
```

By `this value`, it definitely means `ID`, because it doesn't matter what I assign to `ID`.  Note too, that it doesn't matter whether the type is blittable or not, or whether it is heap- or stack-allocated.

Is there some way do declare `ID` as `mutable`?

Comment: maybe a duplicate or at least similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/946338/f-how-do-i-declare-and-use-byref-semantics-on-parameters

Comment: What F# version are you using?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Good point - 4.0.  I've edited the question to include that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have discovered another bug (or undocumented feature?). This happens simply because your parameter name is capitalized. Surprise! :-)

These variants will work (omitted `[<Out>]` for brevity):

```
let bugFix1(id : string byref) = id <- "Hi!"
let bugFix1(iD : string byref) = iD <- "Hi!"
```

But these will fail:

```
let bugFix1(Id : string byref) = Id <- "Hi!"
let bugFix1(ID : string byref) = ID <- "Hi!"
```

I have absolutely no idea why capitalization would matter. I would guess that this never arose before, because parameters always start with a lower-case letter by convention.

I intend to google some more and then file an issue.

Comment: Wow!  That should teach me not to capitalize my abbreviations!  Thanks.

Comment: If you did open an issue, could you add the reference here?